# How to target specific browsers in 2018

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser, target

I used code like:

```
-webkit-
-moz-
@-moz-document url-prefix() {}
```

in the past to target one browser at a time with CSS, but none of these seem to be working any more for me.

Here is the documentation of -webkit- for example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-transition#Browser_compatibility

You can see that it is not recommended any more.

Is there a secure way to target a specific browser (mainly Chrome and Firefox) with CSS?

Comment: In 2018 one don't target specific browsers, one use feature detection with e.g. [CSS `@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

Comment: Furthermore, your question is too broad so if you have a specific issue, narrow it down to avoid it being closed.

Comment: Beyond the above, at http://browserhacks you can find browser specific hacks to target a given browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for @supports

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/08/using-feature-queries-in-css/